# Grouping regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Here is my questions:

I have a very long string with so many values bounded by the different tags. Those values including chinese, english wording and digits.

I wanna to separate by specify pattern. The following is an example:
(I want to find a pattern xxxxxx where xxxx is chinese, english, digits or any notation but not include "<" or ">" as those two symbol is for identify the tags)

However, I found some strange for these pattern. The Pattern seems didn't recgonize the first two tag() but the second one

```
String a = "<f\"number\">4  <f\"number\"><f$n0>14   <h85><f$n0>4    <f$n0>2 <f$n0>2 7   -<f\"Times-Roman\">7<f\"number\">";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<f\"number\">[\\P{sc=Han}*\\p{sc=Han}*[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*^<>]*<f\"number\">");
Matcher m = p.matcher(a);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The output is as same as my String a

Comment: If you need to parse XML/HTML, you should consider using an XML parser.  Regex isn't so hot as handling this.

Comment: sorry miss some info.

Comment: the expected result should be <f"number">4  <f"number">

Answer (score 2):

The character class `[\\P{sc=Han}*\\p{sc=Han}*[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*^<>]*` matches 0 or more any character because `\\P{sc=Han}` and `\\p{sc=Han}` are opposite.

I guess you want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<f\"number\">[\\P{sc=Han}a-zA-Z0-9]*<f\"number\">");
```

You may want to add spaces:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<f\"number\">[\\P{sc=Han}a-zA-Z0-9\s]*<f\"number\">");
```

or:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<f\"number\">[^<]*<f\"number\">");
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this one but the m.group() still return the whole string a any other idea?

Comment: @DickDickSean:You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, it should usefull for future readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer